# Same file extension, but different "Type" in file properties!

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, fonts, file-format, file-type

I have two different files that have same file extensions: `*.otf`. But if I right click on these two files, *Nautilus* shows different "Type:" for them in file properties window: One is `ODF template (application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template)` and other is `OpenType font (application/x-font-otf)`! But I know that both of the files are font files. How to solve this problem?

### Update 1:

Changing default application which is set to open a file by default, does not changes the file MIME type. I selected "Font viewer" as default application for first file, but MIME type was same as before: `ODF template (application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template)`

### Update 2:

Output of `hexdump` and `file` commands for first file `ODF template (application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template)`:

```
~$ hexdump -C /usr/local/share/fonts/PATH/TO/file1.otf | head -10
00000000  00 01 00 00 00 15 01 00  00 04 00 50 44 53 49 47  |...........PDSIG|
00000010  b2 43 b4 f2 00 02 8a a0  00 00 19 14 47 44 45 46  |.C..........GDEF|
00000020  17 64 17 14 00 02 81 e0  00 00 00 8a 47 50 4f 53  |.d..........GPOS|
00000030  4b 22 51 38 00 02 4a 3c  00 00 37 a2 47 53 55 42  |K"Q8..J<..7.GSUB|
00000040  1b 4f b3 32 00 02 1a 38  00 00 30 02 4c 54 53 48  |.O.2...8..0.LTSH|
00000050  62 62 8b 22 00 00 0c 2c  00 00 02 81 4f 53 2f 32  |bb."...,....OS/2|
00000060  8f ff 72 1b 00 00 01 d8  00 00 00 60 56 44 4d 58  |..r........`VDMX|
00000070  66 17 6d 58 00 00 0e b0  00 00 05 e0 63 6d 61 70  |f.mX........cmap|
00000080  f6 42 ff 1e 00 02 82 6c  00 00 08 32 63 76 74 20  |.B.....l...2cvt |
00000090  04 7a 04 1f 00 00 5b d4  00 00 00 4c 66 70 67 6d  |.z....[....Lfpgm|
~$ file /usr/local/share/fonts/PATH/TO/file1.otf 
/usr/local/share/fonts/PATH/TO/file1.otf: TrueType font data
~$ file -i /usr/local/share/fonts/PATH/TO/file1.otf
/usr/local/share/fonts/PATH/TO/file1.otf: application/x-font-ttf; charset=binary
```

Output of `hexdump` and `file` commands for second file `OpenType font (application/x-font-otf)`:

```
~$ hexdump -C /usr/local/share/fonts/PATH/TO/file2.otf | head -10
00000000  4f 54 54 4f 00 0a 00 80  00 03 00 20 43 46 46 20  |OTTO....... CFF |
00000010  5c 33 c3 6d 00 00 09 38  00 00 61 37 47 53 55 42  |\3.m...8..a7GSUB|
00000020  54 d2 12 5e 00 00 6d c0  00 00 05 48 4f 53 2f 32  |T..^..m....HOS/2|
00000030  d2 f6 e7 07 00 00 01 10  00 00 00 60 63 6d 61 70  |...........`cmap|
00000040  19 7f 5b 97 00 00 05 c8  00 00 03 50 68 65 61 64  |..[........Phead|
00000050  fc b9 e6 f6 00 00 00 ac  00 00 00 36 68 68 65 61  |...........6hhea|
00000060  15 93 03 22 00 00 00 e4  00 00 00 24 68 6d 74 78  |...".......$hmtx|
00000070  ac c1 fb 32 00 00 6a 70  00 00 03 50 6d 61 78 70  |...2..jp...Pmaxp|
00000080  00 d4 50 00 00 00 01 08  00 00 00 06 6e 61 6d 65  |..P.........name|
00000090  4d 67 6a ae 00 00 01 70  00 00 04 56 70 6f 73 74  |Mgj....p...Vpost|
~$ file /usr/local/share/fonts/PATH/TO/file2.otf
/usr/local/share/fonts/PATH/TO/file2.otf: OpenType font data
~$ file -i /usr/local/share/fonts/PATH/TO/file2.otf
/usr/local/share/fonts/PATH/TO/file2.otf: application/vnd.ms-opentype; charset=binary
```

## Update 3:

[File 1 link `ODF template (application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template)`](http://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/UthmanTN1-Ver10.zip)
[File 2 link `OpenType font (application/x-font-otf)`](http://alefba.us/download/3237/)

Comment: What is the output of `hexdump -C '/PATH/TO/FILE.otf | head -10` and `file '/PATH/TO/FILE.otf`, & `file -i '/PATH/TO/FILE.otf` for each file?  N.B. If you don't think an answer is good enough don't just downvote it - stay positive :D

Comment: @Wilf The question is updated based on information you asked for. But there is a strange output: the output for **vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template** file contains: `x-font-ttf` and ouput for **x-font-otf** contains `vnd.ms-opentype`!!!  
About the down vote, I agree with you but i could not be  cleared :(.

Comment: If it's a TrueType font then give it .ttf ext. Otherwise maybe put both files in a folder, compress & upload somewhere & provide link. Here is pretty good - http://www.datafilehost.com/

Comment: @doug - using dropbox or google drive share links (if you have them already) is a good idea as those sites can be weird... file1 could be a TTF file so try renaming it and see what happens

Comment: @doug @Wilf link of both files are added. But changing the file extension to `ttf` solved my problem. Please post it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of the problematic file having the wrong extension.

So that threw your file manager off & may have prevented a proper preview of the file.
Seeing that `file UthmanTN1 Ver10.otf` reports `TrueType font data` then simply giving it a proper ext (`.ttf`) should & does resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Files can have different [mime types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) but have the same extension.
That's why you should never fully rely on extension to validate your website uploads.

Take for example `.jpg`, all these are valid mime types:

```
image/pjpeg
image/jpeg
image/jpg
```

[A list of common mime types.](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)

Comment: Your answer just describes root of the problem, that is somewhat clear in my question. But my question is how to solve this problem!

Comment: Your link contradicts your answer. Only valid mime type for .jpg is `image/jpeg`. `image/jpg` is not a real mime type in the first place.